Power Query - How to use a list to refer to an exisitng column of a table
I am using PowerQuery to import data from pdfs. Important are the Titel, ParA, ParB, ParC and the corresponding values WertA, WertB, WertC. The problem ist that columns where I can find the values can vary. The rows didn´t or not as far as I know. I have visualized this in an excel table.
Quelle(https://i.sstatic.net/Y3Kn1ux7.jpg)
My solution is the following
let
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Tiefer gestufte Header" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Quelle),
    #"Transponierte Tabelle1" = Table.Transpose(#"Tiefer gestufte Header"),
     #"Gefilterte Zeilen" = Table.SelectRows(#"Transponierte Tabelle1", each ([Column3] = "titel")),
    Column1 = #"Gefilterte Zeilen"[Column1]
    
in
    Column1

With the correct column I want to filter the original table Quelle as following.
    #"Gefilterte Zeilen1" = Table.SelectRows(Quelle, each ([???] = "titel" and [???] = "ParA" [???] = "ParB" and [???] = "ParB"))

I have tried to use the List Column1 to refer to the correct column (here marked with [???]) but either I got an error or I got an empty table. Does anyone now how I can refer to a column using the list object?
Edit: Sorry, I have tried to make a more precise definition of my problem.
1 let
2    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
3    #"Tiefer gestufte Header" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Quelle),
4    #"Transponierte Tabelle" = Table.Transpose(#"Tiefer gestufte Header"),
5    #"Gefilterte Zeilen" = Table.SelectRows(#"Transponierte Tabelle", each ([Column3] = "test")),
6    // Line 7 creates a List with the name of the Column/Record I want to use. Here "Spalte3".
7    Column1 = #"Gefilterte Zeilen"[Column1],
8    //Line 9 is working as intended.
9    #"Works" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Quelle, Column1{0}, "Test"),
10   //Line 11 and Line 12 results in the same output
11   #"Works2"=Quelle[Spalte3],
12   #"Works3"=Table.Column(Quelle,Column1{0}),
13   // But Line 14 does not work and I do not know why. There must be a difference between Line 11 & 12. I do not understand and how to solve.
14   #"DoesNotWork" = Table.SelectRows(Quelle,each Table.Column(Quelle,Column1{0}) <> null)
15 in
16   #"DoesNotWork"


Something like this will check every column of a row for the word para
each List.Contains(Record.FieldValues(_),"para")
If you want to find the column name in each row that contains aaa then use
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each  Table.ColumnNames(Source){List.PositionOf(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_),each if Text.Contains(_,"aaa") then _ else null),"aaa")})

and later refer to the column as Record.Field(_,"ColumnNameHere")

OK, I do not understand what is purpose for the List.Transform operation. If I use it as it is than I got as a result a column with only error. If skip the List.Transform operation, than I got a column of errors (List.Position returns -1 when the  nothing is found) and one row with the correct column name. But I do not know how this helps? - #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Quelle, "Custom", each Table.ColumnNames(Quelle){List.PositionOf(Record.FieldValues(_),"var1")})

Thank you very much, I have modified your example to fit my efforts.
let
   Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
   #"Gefilterte Zeilen" = Table.SelectRows(Quelle, each List.ContainsAny(Record.FieldValues(_),{"para","parb","parc","pard"}))
in
   #"Gefilterte Zeilen"

But it would be really nice to know how I can convert this List item to table column reference. I hope this is not impolite.

do not add comments as a new answer. I have edited my answer above if that helps

You'd better organize your filter table something like this:

Suppose you've called this table as Tabelle1.
Then you can use following code to filter your original table Quelle:
FilterValues = Table.ToRecords(
    Table.SelectRows(
        Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
        each not([Column] is null)
    )
),
#"Gefilterte Zeilen1" = Table.SelectRows(Quelle, each List.Accumulate(FilterValues, true, (state, current) => state and (try Record.Field(_, current[Column]) = current[Value] otherwise false)))

This will filter your table to select only records where all columns having names listed in table Tabelle1 have stated values.
If all values in filter are non-empty text values you can alsj apply this code:
Filter = List.Accumulate(FilterValues, "true", (state, current) => (state & " and (rec[#""" & current[Column] & """] = " & """" & current[Value] &""")") ) ,
#"Gefilterte Zeilen1" = Table.SelectRows(Quelle, each Expression.Evaluate(Filter, [rec = _]))


The data I try to import are from an analytical system. The only way to export is pdf. I am not joking. When I am importing the date, the values, I am looking for, can be in different columns (!). I have tried the code. But I suggest you assume that ParA, ParB, ParC are always in the same column. Otherwise, I am making something wrong.

You can change ParA,.. for any column names which presented in your pdf. So you can fill the table Tabelle1 with any combinations of column names and values. But may be I have not understood your issue correctly. If you clarify with examples I think I would help.
May be your task is to find dates/values in any column?
